# How to add a row with Html.TextBox() on a table using jquery

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

I have added the Html element to the table with table row but,i am getting problem with adding the Html.TextBox() to the table with a table row using j Query when a button is clicked.

Answer (score 1):

jQuery and Javascript are not ASP. A TextBox is an `<input>` element with `type="text"`. To add one to any given element:

```
$('#someElement').append($('<input type="text" />'));
```